# Drafting an Elastic Search Template via Elastic Console

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack, mustache

Im totally new to the whole elastic search thingy so bare with me;

I've created an index (my-search-index) which has the following document structure :

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| item_code | String |
| item_name | String |
| item_price | Float |
| merchant_name | String |
| merchant_location | Location [lon,lat] |
| merchant_phone | String |
| merchant_address | String |
| receipt_date | Timestamp |

How can I create an Elastic search template for my search application : "search-elastic-client" which searches "my-search-index" with the following rules :

User sends

- query_string [String] : the string to be searched in fields  item_name and/or item_code
- user_lat [Float] : the user's current Latitude
- user_lon [Float] : the user's current Longitude

Search result :

I need to return **top 5 merchants** results with merchant_name, merchant_phone, merchant_address, merchant_location Ordered by

- **item_price** best price and
- **merchant_location** nearness to the user's provided location.

Appreciate your help